# I tried to run t-test in Excel using VBA, encountering "objects required" error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ttest()
Application.Run (ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Pttestv), ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(5771, ActiveCell.Column)), ActiveSheet.Range("$BU$1", "$BU$5771"), ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5785, ActiveCell.Column - 3), Cells(5797, ActiveCell.Column)), "", False, 0.05
End Sub
```

I am not very certain about the arguments in t-test in Excel.
I assume the arguments are "Application.Run (ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Pttestv), **Input range 1**, **Input range 2**, **output range**,.... "

However, I keep encountering "objects required" error. Could someone plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the simple error in this code is that

`Application.run (ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Pttestv)`

should be

`Application.run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Pttestv"`

Sorry for bothering!